# how to set a default arguments for a generic template class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a generic template class. I would like the default element of the class to be instantiated with std::array of 3 ints {0,0,0} however, I don't know how to place the default list of arguments.
My goal:

`Vec<> a;` -> creates a vec3 with an array {0,0,0} as private member

`Vec<int,3> b;` -> the same as above

`Vec<int,2> c;` -> creates a vec with array {0,0}

`Vec<double,3> d(4,5,9);` -> creates a vec with {4,5,9} as doubles

My code,
vec.h

```
template<typename T = int, int N = 3>
class Vec{
public:
    Vec(T v0,T v1) : vec_coordinates_ ({v0,v1} = {0,0}){
        static_assert(N == 2, "wrong number of arguments");
    };
    Vec(T v0,T v1,T v2) : vec_coordinates_ ({v0,v1,v2}){
        static_assert(N == 3, "wrong number of arguments");
    };

    private:
     std::array<T,N> vec_coordinates_;
 }
```

doesn't compile.
The constructor for an array with two elements works.

```
Vec(T v0,T v1) : vec_coordinates_ ({v0,v1} = {0,0}) {
static_assert(N == 2, "wrong number of arguments");};
```

The above compiles, however

```
    Vec3(T v0,T v1,T v2) : vec_coordinates_ ({v0,v1,v2} = {0,0,0}) { //C2059
    static_assert(N == 3, "wrong number of arguments");
    };
```

does not compile. I get the error:

> error C2059: syntax error: '='

on the line with {0,0,0}.

I don't understand the difference, why the {0,0} compiles and the array with 3 zeros doesn't. I would be very grateful for any tips or pieces of advice.

Comment: what is `({v0,v1} = {0,0})` supposed to do?

Comment: it is supposed to ensure that Vec<int,2> b; would result in a an object b that has a private std::array of vec_coordinates_ that equals {0,0}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::initializer_list` to get it done.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename T = int, int N = 3>
class Vec {
    /**
     * You can have this here. 
     * Its neat and for people who goes through this object it'll be easy for them to understand.
     * Also you don't have to have one of this in every constructor this way.
     */
    static_assert(N == 2, "wrong number of arguments");

public:
    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * This sets the array's values to 0.
     */
    Vec() {
        std::memset(vec_coordinates_.data(), 0, sizeof(T) * N);
    }

    Vec(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
        std::memcpy(vec_coordinates_.data(), list.begin(), sizeof(T) * N);
    };

private:
    std::array<T, N> vec_coordinates_;
};

int main()
{
    Vec<int, 2> a = { 0, 1 };
}
```

> I don't understand the difference, why the {0,0} compiles and the array with 3 zeros doesn't. I would be very grateful for any tips or pieces of advice.

Do you understand what's happening in `{v0,v1,v2} = {0,0,0}` and `{v0,v1} = {0,0}`? What your trying to do is something which is not allowed to do in C++. Your assigning a *lvalue* to another *lvalue* and assign it to a variable. In other words, what you have done is something like this:

```cpp
int i = 10 = 10;
```

Now you see why the error comes?

Comment: one more thing - how to place the default values for an object generated with initializers list? So that Vec<int,2> b;  resolves to {0,0} ?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```cpp
template<typename T = int, int N = 3>
class Vec{
public:
    Vec(T v0 = 0,T v1 = 0) : vec_coordinates_ ({v0,v1}){
        static_assert(N == 2, "wrong number of arguments");
    };
    Vec(T v0 = 0,T v1 = 0,T v2 = 0) : vec_coordinates_ ({v0,v1,v2}){
        static_assert(N == 3, "wrong number of arguments");
    };

    private:
     std::array<T,N> vec_coordinates_;
 };
```

Also, as far as I know, std:array<int, N> will initialize itself with "zeros" automatically (may depend on compiler actually), so adding empty constructor should do the trick (+ you don't have to worry if one uses some strange T)